# In Apache two directories with same privilege behave differently

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, centos

I have an Apache server running on Centos 7, it is a wordpress site. There is a directory ../wp/wp-content/phpfiles with these files, rights and owners:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache 4096 Apr  6 15:45 .
4 drwxr-xr-x. 8 apache apache 4096 Apr  6 15:15 ..
4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache 3182 Apr  5 14:50 header.php
4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache  941 Apr  4 14:41 jsonhandler.php
4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache   77 Apr  5 13:34 load.php
4 drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Apr  6 14:54 push
4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache  190 Apr  5 09:27 settings.ini
4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache   52 Apr  4 15:49 test.php
```

When I view this page in a browser, I get this:

```
Index of /wp/wp-content/phpfiles
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory
[TXT]   header.php  2016-04-05 14:50    3.1K
[TXT]   jsonhandler.php 2016-04-04 14:41    941
[TXT]   load.php    2016-04-05 13:34    77
[DIR]   push/   2016-04-06 14:54    -
[   ]   settings.ini    2016-04-05 09:27    190
[TXT]   test.php    2016-04-04 15:49    52
```

In the directory listing above, there is directory 'push', these are the files, rights and owners for that directory:

```
 4 drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache  4096 Apr  6 14:54 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache  4096 Apr  6 15:45 ..
 4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache  2649 Apr  6 14:54 header.php
 4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache   941 Apr  6 14:54 jsonhandler.php
 4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache    34 Apr  6 14:54 load.php
 4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache  1284 Apr  6 14:54 sendpush.php
 4 -r--r--r--. 1 apache apache   177 Apr  6 14:54 settings.ini
```

When I view that file in a browser (by clicking on the link for push) I get a 403 server error, it will not even list the contents. But I do not understand why I get this, the files all have read-rights and have the same owner. Can Anyone explain?

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://serverfault.com/ as it's not strictly speaking a programming issue.

Comment: Have you checked the selinux contexts?

Comment: It sounds like you have directory browsing disabled, either in an Apache config file or a .htaccess file. Look for the term `Indexes` in Apache config, a vhost config or a .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, it turned out that @Etan had the correct answer. I had to use 'ls -Z'  to find the security context, and they were different for a number of files. I used the Linux 'chcon'  command to change them.

Comment: It seems I can not mark @etan-reisner as the one with the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't file an answer. I posted a comment with a question that happened to lead you in the right direction.